# Bootstrap 4 stacking radio btn-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I have a btn-group of radio buttons which I want to stack responsively.
I simply can't get it to work except when I remove the btn-group but then the radio buttons of course don't know which ones are checked and simply stop working.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label class="btn btn-primary active"><input hidden="true" type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label class="btn btn-primary"><input hidden="true"  type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label class="btn btn-primary"><input hidden="true" type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what do you want exactly? value of checked radio button or active class on checked radio button?

Comment: @AbhishekKumbhani I need the active class

Comment: @n-wasserkampf Actually bootstrap automatically add an active class. Here is the [demo link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNRyPJ). Make sure you have added bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js and jquery.js files correctly.

Comment: @AbhishekKumbhani Thanks I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve that by adding this script :

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change",function(){
    $('input:checked').parent().addClass("active"); // Change active with your own class name
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified it a little to fit my needs, thanks a lot!